# Emacs - how to see/how to debug a single elisp function/emacs command

Tags: emacs, elisp

There is one thing that I don't like on table function in Org-mode for emacs. I would like to see all the functions that get executed by function that I run as Emacs command.

What is the best way to do that? Any tips how to get started with debuging elisp code, especially single command of interest?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> *function name* to find the source code for the function.
2. <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-M-x</kbd> to instrument the function for Edebug.

Whenever the function is called, Emacs will drop into Edebug which makes it easy to execute the function step by step, inspect variables, and do other typical debugging tasks. See `(info "(Elisp)Edebug")` for more information.

Comment: Some platforms, such as Gnome 3, don't allow Emacs to receive `C-M-x`. So to instrument the function with edebug, use `C-u M-x eval-defun`.

Answer (score 17):

I prefer the traditional Emacs debugger to edebug.  To use it:

```
M-x debug-on-entry the-function RET
```

Then, whenever `the-function` is invoked, the debugger is entered. Use <kbd>d</kbd> to step through the evaluation, and <kbd>c</kbd> if you want to skip through a step (not dive into its details.

It helps to view the definition of `the-function` in another window/frame while you step through it.

You can cancel `debug-on-entry` using `M-x cancel-debug-on-entry`.

Comment: How do you disable this once it's enabled?

Answer (score 0):

`C-h f` to go to function help mode, then type the name of the function. If it is an elisp function, you can then view the source and look for yourself what functions it calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a programmatic way to see the source of a function (akin to Clojure's `source` macro) you can use the `symbol-function` subroutine.

For instance, there is a defun `do-math` in my `.emacs` file.  To see its source, I can do the following

`(symbol-function 'do-math)`

and it gives me

```
ELISP> (symbol-function 'do-math)
(lambda
  (expression)
  (interactive "sexpression:")
  (insert
   (number-to-string
    (eval
     (read expression)))))
```

See also :
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Indirection.html

See also also :
http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_symbol.html